what off the shelf chemicals break the factory adhesive bonding paper gaskets to a steel plate in an automatic transmission?
The adhesive chemical is unknown.  This part is constantly exposed to temperatures from -20F to 300F, and is submerged is transmission fluid.  The exact steel that the gaskets are bonded to is unkown, but it is soft and ferrous. The paper composition is unknown, but the paper is +/- .010" thick.

Rather than cobble together your own chemicals to make a gasket remover, you might better use a commercial product, such as Permatex Gasket Remover or CRC® Gasket Remover, and careful scraping with a sharp blade, as described at Mechanics StackExchange.
Why not roll-your-own? Because these commercial products have gone through the process of safety testing, have safety data sheets, such as this from CRC that list all the hazards, as well as the constituents (acetone, liquefied petroleum gas, N-methyl-2-pyrrolidone, xylene, ethylbenzene, toluene), and describe (comparatively) safe use of the product.
Yes, you could buy that slew of ingredients, but in small quantities, it would be far cheaper to buy the compounded product in a pressurized container.
Caveat
The author admits some personal bias towards the company that gave us the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, as well as math tables and other tools. ;-)

All hail the Chemical Rubber Company!
